# What makes the difference between direct and indirect access to volatile objects in C?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, stm32, volatile

I am dealing with hardware registers on an STM32 controller.

I have defined a bunch of structures like the following:

```
#define PACKED __attribute__ ((packed))
#define ASSERT(cond) _Static_assert(cond, #cond)

typedef union {
    struct PACKED {
        uint16_t value;
        uint16_t reserved;
    };
    uint32_t bits;
} LOL_LPTIM_16_BIT_VALUE;

ASSERT(sizeof(LOL_LPTIM_16_BIT_VALUE) == sizeof(uint32_t)); // OK
```

Then, I have a structure like this:

```
typedef struct PACKED {
    // ...
    volatile LOL_LPTIM_16_BIT_VALUE autoreload;
    // ...
} LOL_LPTIM;
```

The offset of the `autoreload` field in the structure agrees with the documentation. I also have the following objects available (following the documentation and header files provided by ST):

```
#define LOL_LPTIM1_BASE (LOL_APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x7C00UL)
#define LOL_LPTIM2_BASE (LOL_APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x9400UL)

#define LOL_LPTIM1 ((volatile LOL_LPTIM *) LOL_LPTIM1_BASE)
#define LOL_LPTIM2 ((volatile LOL_LPTIM *) LOL_LPTIM2_BASE)
```

I have a `static const` structure that stores these pointers:

```
static const struct {
    volatile LOL_LPTIM *lptim;
} timer[2] = {
    { .lptim = LPTIM1 },
    { .lptim = LPTIM2 }
}
```

Now, when I write

```
*(uint32_t *) &(timer[0].lptim->autoreload.bits) = 0xffff;
```

or

```
*(uint16_t *) &(timer[0].lptim->autoreload.value) = 0xffff;
```

the code works correctly, but when I write

```
timer[0].lptim->autoreload.bits = 0xffff;
```

(which should be exactly equivalent) or

```
timer[0].lptim->autoreload.value = 0xffff;
```

then it does not work as expected - it works differently than the indirected variant, and the value of the `autoreload` register doesn't seem to be set properly (the perpipherals behave differently).

What could be a possible reason of this discrepancy?

Godbolt shows that the compiler generates very different set of operations for these two cases: https://godbolt.org/z/cno9yf

They get more similar when the indirect version is changed to

```
*(volatile uint32_t *) &(timer[0].lptim->autoreload.bits) = 0xffff;
```

(there's many more instructions in the output)

Comment: "Does not work as expected"?  What does that mean?  Your code goes bowling?

Comment: @AndrewHenle for one, it works differently than in the first case. In particular, it seems that I'm unable to set the value of the autoreload register properly when I don't use the indirection.

Comment: Rather than just saying "it works differently" can you be specific about what the difference is? eg "In the first case it does XXX but in the second case it does YYY". This will help people understand what the issue might be.

Comment: @psmears I'm working on a rather specific application. I am using some peripherals to do measurements. In one case, the peripherals are set up properly, while in the second case they aren't. I don't think that the specifics are relevant to the issue, which is that seemingly equivalent code produces different behavior.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. `volatile` has its semantics, namely each access to it should translate into an actual access to the underlying memory/device. Such a guarantee does not exist for non-`volatile` access. Casting to a non-volatile type is a bad idea too.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The question is why the indirected assignments work differently than the direct ones (what are the possible reasons why they differ)

Comment: You are interested in writing a value into a physical register. The only correct way to do it is to have it accessed as `volatile` object. Any other way would be wrong and can lead to any result (including seemingly working one).

Comment: the problem is not here. The generated code is identical. https://godbolt.org/z/kjkGaV

Comment: @P__J__ that's exactly what I would expect. Yet, the only thing I change in my code is this assignment. In practice, I have a bit more indirection: I have a `const` array storing a structure which contains the `LOL_LPTIM1` or `LOL_LPTIM2` pointers, but other than that, it's the only difference between a working version and the one that fails.

Comment: @P__J__ I have modified the code to resemble my version more, and the generated code seems to differ significantly https://godbolt.org/z/cno9yf

Comment: @MaciekGodek you simple use packing and volatile without any need. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is packing the structures when it is not needed. You also overuse volatile.

Be very careful packing the structures and unions as it prevents many code optimisations. Do not use them "just in case".

Here you have the correct version.

https://godbolt.org/z/GNjmUX

Comment: The whole point of using `__attribute__((packed))` and `volatile` is to prevent undesired optimizations (because I'm writing to hardware ports). It is unclear to me why the `volatile` specifiers are "overused" in my example.

Comment: It is a very bad practice to make volatile the whole data structures. packed attribute should be only used if there is a rick of having padding between the struct members. There is no the issue here.  I know what you want to archieve.

Comment: AFAIK compiler is free to insert any padding between struct members (especially if they are unpacked). Your answer doesn't give any clues as of why "it is a very bad practice to make volatile the whole data structures".

Comment: @MaciekGodek you do not have to use my answer and I am not paid to give you one. Be nice to people who try to help you. I am out

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
*(uint32_t *) &(timer[0].lptim->autoreload.bits) = 0xffff;
```

you cast away the volatile qualifer on the address, so this will be a non-volatile write of the field (so might be optimized away if there are later similar writes to the same address.)  With

```
timer[0].lptim->autoreload.bits = 0xffff;
```

the access will be volatile, so cannot be so optimized.

Comment: it is not the issue here. The first uses compile time computed address - and compiler knows that it is aligned. The latter is runtime calculated and there is a possibility of unaligned access. Packed struct can be accessed by the instructions requiring aligned access - and compiler generates the byte accesses.  OP is just packing structs when it is not needed. Very common beginners mistake.

Comment: @P__J__: the two addresses are identical -- and are compile time constant.  The only difference is the volatile (or not)